# mod_ssl with FIPS mode enabled and SSLRandomSeed

Tags: openssl, fips, mod-ssl

I have traced through the **mod_ssl** and the **OpenSSL** FIPS code as best I can and I believe that the `SSLRandomSeed` configuration parameter given in the `mod_ssl.conf` file simply doesn't do anything useful when FIPS mode is enabled in mod_ssl.

Tracing the code in `ssl_init_Module()` appears to show that the function `ssl_rand_seed()` is called before FIPS mode is set.  `ssl_rand_seed()` will perform seeding from the given SSLRandomSeed defined source(s), but once you switch to FIPS mode, the DRBG is re-created from scratch without retaining any of the information.

In fact, OpenSSL's FIPS mode appears to go out of its way to source from /dev/urandom, /dev/random and /dev/srandom (in that order) according to the DEVRANDOM macro defined in the OpenSSL base code e_os.h when compiled for a standard Linux target.

**Does anyone have any experience with this combination?**

Can they comment on how to provide a run-time selected entropy source such as a processed file?  Do I have to recompile OpenSSL and supplying a new DEVRANDOM definition each time I want to change my randomness source?

Answer (score 0):

> Can they comment on how to provide a run-time selected entropy source such as a processed file? Do I have to recompile OpenSSL and supplying a new DEVRANDOM definition each time I want to change my randomness source?

I think there's three issues here. First, what is used for the PRNG when operating in FIPS mode; second, how do you seed the generator; and third, how does Apache/mod_ssl integrate with the first two.

First, when `FIPS_mode_enable` succeeds, then the default OpenSSL generator of `md_rand` is switched out. The DRBG used is specified in [SP800-90](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-90A/SP800-90A.pdf) (sans the Dual-EC generator). By default, that's the AES/CTR generator. You are correct in that the previous seed is not longer used. This is discussed in general on the [Random Numbers](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) OpenSSL wiki page.

Second, the generator auto-seeds itself to ensure its in good working order. You can still call `RAND_seed` to add entropy to the generator because the RAND interface is pretty much agnostic to the underlying generator. This is discussed in general on the [Random Numbers](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) OpenSSL wiki page.

Third, there's a disconnect between Apache/mod_ssl and OpenSSL. Apparently, Apache/mod_ssl does not know about these details. You will probably need to write some glue code that understands how to work with OpenSSL and the `RAND_*` interface in particular. Perhaps you can do this by providing a custom mod.